# Rest In Place gem Success Event Callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm trying to call a success callback on an element being updated via the [Rest In Place gem](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place#events).

I have a helper in Rails that produces the following code in the DOM:

```
<span class="rest-in-place" id="rip-name" data-attribute="name" data-formtype="input">Alan Smithee</span>
```

And when I bind the success event, `success.rest-in-place`, to the editable element like so in a coffeescript file...

```
$('#rip-name').bind 'success.rest-in-place', (event, data) ->
    alert 'anything?'
    return
```

I get no results despite the attribute being successfully updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and to run it successfully I had to make two small changes:

1. The coffeescript code binding the `success` event **must be run after the page is loaded**, e.g. after the `document.ready` event:

   ```
   $(document).ready ->
      $('#rip-name').bind 'success.rest-in-place', (event, data) ->
         alert 'anything?'
         return
   ```
2. I also had to add a `data-object="user"` to the RIP-enabled span so that RIP passed the `name` parameter under the `user` key (I tested your code on a test `User` model). You may not need this though, perhaps your controller accepts a bare `name` parameter. And you yourself state that the tag updates successfully.

Other than that, you code should be perfectly OK and triggered the alert in my test scenario.